# Is it predicative or object clause?

Tags: subordinate-clauses, licensing, complementation

Could you tell me what type of subordinate clause it is: **predicative or object?**

> I felt (or had a feeling) **that they had no objections.**

I know that if we have such construction: "I felt **as if** they had no objections" - the subordinate clause is predicative, but the sentence structure and meaning are different from my sentence,right?

Answer (score 1):

*Feel* enters into at least four different syntactic constructions:

> He felt sick ... *Here the adjective* sick *is a Predicate Complement attributed to the Subject*.
>
> He felt dismay ... *Here the noun* dismay *is the Direct Object; but it signifies an emotion or sensation, a 'feeling', which again is attributed to the Subject. The same structure is exhibited by the 90s catchphrase* I feel your pain.
>
> He felt as if he had been punched ... *Here the comparative clause* as if he had been punched *is technically an adverbial, but again it effectively attributes a sensation or emotion to the Subject. It 'implies' a nominal Object which the comparative preposition phrase modifies*.

In these *feel* has the sense "experience some emotion in oneself". In the fourth construction, *feel* has the sense "perceive imprecisely or without certainty":

> He felt {**that / ∅**} they had no objections ... *Here the clause* they had no objections *is the Direct Object. The complementizer* that *may be omitted. This may also be used with noun phrases*: He felt their satisfaction.

*HAVE a feeling* works a little differently. Noun phrase complements of *feeling* are expressed with *of*:

> He had a feeling **of** dismay.
> He had a feeling **of** their satisfaction. (*This is fairly rare*.)

In effect, the preposition also acts as a complementizer; this is the case, too, with preposition phrases headed by *as if*:

> He had a feeling **as if** he had been punched.

A clausal object, however, has its own complementizer, either *that* or *∅*:

> He had a feeling {**that / ∅**} they had no objections.

But all this is on the margins of grammatical analysis, whether your grammar is Traditional or Modern.